# Sort com Número e String - não ordena para um número

Tags: javascript

Tenho um array de objetos como o abaixo:

```
[ {"code":1,"name": "01 - teste um"},
  {"code":8,"name": "02 - teste dois"},
  {"code":32,"name": "209 - teste teste"} ...]
```

Preciso ordenar esse array pela chave `name`. Observe que essa chave pode ser somente string, exemplo "teste", mas também pode ter um numeral na frente ("06 - teste") com um hífen/traço ou um ponto (`07 . teste três`).

A função que estou usando para ordenação segue abaixo.

```
var arrayOrdenado = array.sort(function( a, b ) { 
    var a_nome = a.name;
    var b_nome = b.name;
    if (a_nome && a_nome.indexOf(".")>-1){
        var a_nome = a_nome.substr(0, a_nome.indexOf("."));
        a_nome = parseFloat(a_nome);
    } else if (a_nome && a_nome.indexOf("-")>-1){
        var a_nome = a_nome.substr(0, a_nome.indexOf("-"));
        a_nome = parseFloat(a_nome);
    } 

    if (b_nome && b_nome.indexOf(".")>-1){
        var b_nome = b_nome.substr(0, b_nome.indexOf("."));
        b_nome = parseFloat(b_nome);
    } else if (b_nome && b_nome.indexOf("-")>-1){
        var b_nome = b_nome.substr(0, b_nome.indexOf("-"));
        b_nome = parseFloat(b_nome);
    }

    if ( a_nome < b_nome ) return -1;
    if ( a_nome > b_nome ) return 1;
    return 0;
});
```

O código ordena corretamente.

Porém, para o `name` "06 - teste" fica fora de ordem. O mais estranho é que isso só acontece para o número 06.

Não estou conseguindo achar o erro, pois como mencionado o array é ordenado corretamente exceto pelo numeral "06".

Comment: Pra mim funciona: https://ideone.com/A0ibAw - **Palpite**: existem [vários caracteres diferentes que são semelhantes ao hífen](http://jkorpela.fi/dashes.html#unidash), pode ser que no caso do "06" ele tenha um desses caracteres, pois aí `indexOf` não o encontra e o 06 acaba não sendo ordenado pelo valor numérico, veja um exemplo usando o "em dash" (um "hífen mais comprido"): https://ideone.com/pDiY03

Comment: Pra saber se o problema é esse mesmo, vc pode percorrer os caracteres da string e imprimir seus codepoints (assim: https://ideone.com/pLiXLQ) - o codepoint do hífen é `2d`, se aparecer algum valor diferente no lugar, é porque é um desses outros caracteres que mencionei (e aí o `indexOf` não vai encontrar mesmo)